# Angular Chosen - Don't bind ng-model to entire object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chosen

Using Angular Chosen

https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

and testing out the following example

```
<select multiple
        chosen
        ng-model="state"
        ng-options="s.name for s in states">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

However, I'm wondering as to how one would bind just the name value for a state object to ng-model?

The options presented will display just the state names, but when chosen, the entire state object is bound to ng-model rather than just the selected name.

Any thoughts would be much appreictaed as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this format

```
select as label for value in array
```

eg. `s.name as s.name for s in states`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.